# Scheduled tasks on Server 2019 don't work when user is not signed on

Tags: scheduled-task

I have about 30 VB Apps that are humming along on a Windows 2008 server using scheduled tasks.    They all do a variety of simple to complex tasks from pulling data and merging letters on a monthly basis, posting data on our website, converting data to crystal reports, etc.

It’s now past the time for us to get off of our Windows 2008 server so I’m taking the apps and converting them up from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2019.    No real hurdles.   Everything is converting fairly clean and running great.

Problems begin when I set the apps up on Windows Server 2019.    We have a user that is used for processing tasks and has the appropriate rights on the server.   If the tasks are setup to run overnight and I leave the server signed on, the tasks process fine.    If I sign off of the server the tasks show that they ran and that they completed successfully, but never finish processing.   The status shows they completed at the same time the schedule is triggered, and most of the tasks normally should run 15 minutes to an hour.

Nothing in the event log to say it failed, and I have a good bit of error code built into each program that would fire an error if one was triggered.

The task is setup to “Run whether user is logged on or not”, and also “Run with highest privileges”.

Did something change since 2008 regarding scheduled tasks that I should be aware of?    Any suggestions / help with this is appreciated.

Comment: The return code displayed in task scheduler is 0x0 ?

Answer (score 0):

By default activity history in scheduled task is not enabled, enable it for going much deeper in this scenario, you can do it with:

```
.1 Opening an Elevated Task Scheduler (i.e. right-click the Task Scheduler icon and select 
   Run as Administrator)

.2 In the Actions pane (right pane, not actions tab), click Enable all activity history
```

Try to run the job as SYSTEM account

With newer versions of Task Scheduler, the user account running the task needs to have full control permissions for the folder of the program you are running.